# how to integrate beyondcode laravel websocket replacement for pusher on ubuntu live server running ssl

Tags: reactjs, laravel-echo, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

am using beyondcode laravel websocket `beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.14",` which is the replacement for pusher, php pusher `pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2"` laravel echo `"laravel-echo": "^1.15.0",` and vite for react since frontend is react `"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",` which i have used to develop a real time chat application.

**here is my setup**

*my env setting*

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=some_id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=some_app_key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=some_secrete
PUSHER_HOST="https://example.com"
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

*my echo setting inside bootstrap.js setting*

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST,
    wssHost:import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    // disableStats:true,
    forceTLS: true, //since its on ssl 
    encrypted:true, //since its on ssl 
    enableTransports:['ws','wss'],
    auth:{
        headers:{
            'XSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
        }
    }
});
```

*my broadcasting connection setting*

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => env(PUSHER_HOST),
                'port' => env(PUSHER_PORT),
                'scheme' => env(PUSHER_SCHEME)
            ],
        ],
]
```

*my websocket setting*

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

with these settings, when i run then same on localhost changing host to 127.0.0.1 it is working just fine but when i deploy it on a live web server and getting the following errors

1. when i want to connect in the `https://example.com/laravel-websocket` which is the dashboard for the web socket am getting **channel current state is unavailable**
   [error on click connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Cgr.png)
2. after clicking on connect in the console am getting `pusher.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:6001/app/some_app_key?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed:`

can anyone have a clue to solve these issues since i can not connect to the dashboard therefore i can not send or receive real time chats

i tried replacing the domain with my public address but still not wroking
i tried to turn `forceTLS: true, encrypted:true,` to false

Comment: Hi! Have you ever found a solution? Because I'm struggling with the same thing right now.

Comment: No i think the problem was to do with the ubuntu server and also the pusher/pusher-php-server version !